# Shopping Cart. Error

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
print ("Welcome to our Shop")

class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def getName(self):     #Returning name of Item.
        return self.name
    def getPrice(self):    #Returning price of Item.
        return self.price

class Cart:
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = []         #List is Cart, you will store items in it.

    def addItem(self, item):
        self.item = list.append(self.list)    #Adding item to Cart(List).

    def getTotal(self):        #Total price. Your bill.
        total = 0   
        for item in self.list:
            total += price
            return total

    def numItems(self):      #Number of items in your cart.
        items = 0
        for item in self.list:
            items += item

def kart():
    item1 = Item("Xbox", 350)
    item2 = Item("Controller", 50)      #Items to buy.
    item3 = Item("LED TV 55", 550)
    k = Cart()                          #Calling Cart Class.
    k.addItem(item1)
    k.addItem(item2)                    #Adding Items.
    k.addItem(item3)
    print ("You have %i items in your cart for a total of %s $" %(k.numItems(), k.getTotal()))

korpa = kart()
```

I get error at the end. It says

```
Welcome to our ShoTraceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Marko\Documents\Projects\EbayCart.py", line 41, in <module>
p
korpa = kart()                          
File "C:\Users\Marko\Documents\Projects\EbayCart.py", line 35, in kart
k = Cart()                          #Calling Cart Class.
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

I was reading

```
__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

posts, but it didn't help in my case.
Do you have any ideas what's problem?
I'm learning Classes right now and that's purpose of this code.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Look at your `Cart.__init__`. How many arguments does it take? Two. How many did you provide it with? Only one (the implicit `self`). Also, `self.item = list.append(self.list)` looks very odd and will result in another error. Even more, the indentation's off in `Cart.getTotal`. Finally, `Cart.numItems` returns `None`, which isn't what you want.

Comment: i.e. you need to specify `list`.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining cart init to have a list parameter

```
def __init__(self, list)
```

but then call it without parameters:

```
k = Cart()
```

According to your init definition you would have to create an instance with an empty list by something like

```
k = Cart([])
```

But when you look closer to the `init` function you see that in fact you don't use the `list`, so just drop it like this:

```
class Cart:
     def __init__(self):
         self.list = []         #List is Cart, you will store items in it.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` of Cart takes an argument `list`, which you probably don't really need to supply, since it's just an empty list which you are filling later. You can just change the classes init to

```
def __init__(self):
    self.list = []
```

The addition of the items to the list is also not working as it should, but I think it's better if you first try to solve that problem yourself... :)